# How to minify css using gruntjs

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am trying to minify an external css script using gruntjs and [grunt-css](https://github.com/jzaefferer/grunt-css) plugin through the terminal.

The code I am running:

```
grunt --cssmin ../style.css > ../style1.css
```

Am I doing it right? Am I misunderstanding what Grunt is used for?

Thanks!

Here is what my generated style1.css looks like... It's not minified.. I'm not sure what it is but it is doing something.

```
[31m<[39m[33mWARN[39m[31m>[39m [33mTask "cssmin" not found. Use --force to continue.[39m [31m</[39m[33mWARN[39m[31m>[39m
```

[31mAborted due to warnings.[39m

Comment: Well, are you getting an error?  If so, what is it.  If you're not, does your `style1.css` look different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not exactly how Grunt works. Grunt uses a grunt file (`grunt.js` in v0.3 and `Gruntfile.js` in v0.4) to configure build instructions. First create a grunt file, `grunt init:gruntfile` and specify your css min targets there. I recommend reading the getting started guide in the Grunt docs:
https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/Getting-started

You can use Sqwish (what grunt-css uses) directly to do the above. Install sqwish globally with `npm install -g sqwish` then type: `sqwish -o ../style1.css ../style.css`. Read more about Sqwish here: https://github.com/ded/sqwish